# Show that $(\phi_{n}^{(n)})^{-1}= -(\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(\phi_{i}^{(n)})^{-1})$

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, numerical-methods

So I have $n+1$ points $x_{0},x_{1},...,x_{n} \in \mathbb{R}$ and a following quasi-function:

$\phi_{j}^{(n)}=\prod_{i=0,i \neq j}^{n}(x_{j}-x_{i})$

Show that $(\phi_{n}^{(n)})^{-1}= -(\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(\phi_{i}^{(n)})^{-1})$

Comment: Should that be $xi$ or $x_i$?

Comment: $x_{i}$ all the way, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: look at what happens when $n=2$, and see if you can generalize:

$$-\sum_{i=0}^{2-1} \left(\phi_i^{(n)}\right)^{-1} = -\left(\frac{1}{(x_0-x_1)(x_0-x_2)} + \frac{1}{(x_1-x_0)(x_1-x_2)}\right)$$
$$ = -\frac{(x_1-x_2)-(x_0-x_2)}{(x_0-x_1)(x_0-x_2)(x_1-x_2)}$$
$$= \frac{1}{(x_2-x_0)(x_2-x_1)}$$
$$=\left(\phi_2^{(2)}\right)^{-1}$$

Answer (score 1):

Consider the polynomials

$$\Psi_j(X) = \prod_{\substack{i=0\\i\neq j}}^n (X - x_i)$$

of degree $n$. Also consider the polynomial

$$L(X) = \sum_{i=0}^n \frac{\Psi_i(X)}{\phi_i^{(n)}}$$

of degree $d \leqslant n$. Evidently we have $\Psi_i(x_i) = \phi_i^{(n)}$ and $\Psi_i(x_j) = 0$ for $j \neq i$, so

$$L(x_i) = 1,\quad 0 \leqslant i \leqslant n,$$

hence $L \equiv 1$. The coefficient of $X^n$ in $L$ is?

Comment: I'm so sorry, but I still don't get it completely. What is this sentence - 'The coefficient of $X^{n}$ in $L$ is?'- getting at? I don't see how those helper polynomials changed anything...

Comment: Determine the coefficient of $X^n$ in $L$ in two ways, one of them is closely related to your problem. Together the two ways solve the problem.